# Metadata version mismatch found version 4, expected 3 in barcode-scanner

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Currently I am working with barcode-scanner reader in ionic. 
While `ionic serve` the build is successfully processing. 
But `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` 
I am getting below error.

> Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/index.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3
>           at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
>           at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
>           at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
>           at /var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23023:30
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at extractProgramSymbols (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
>           at AotCompiler.compileAll (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
>           at CodeGenerator.codegen (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:30:14)
>           at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:61:30)
>           at /var/www/html/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:182:73

I did't know what to do. 
Please give me some suggestions to resolve this issue.

```
import {BarcodeScanner} from "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner";


scanQR() {
        let options = {
            prompt: "Place a Qr code inside the scan area",
        };

        this._barcodeScanner.scan(options).then((barcodeData) => {
            if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
                console.log("User cancelled the action!");
                return false;
            }
            if (barcodeData.text) {
                alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + barcodeData.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + barcodeData.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + barcodeData.cancelled);
                this.navCtrl.pop();
            } else {
                this.navCtrl.pop();
            }
        }, (err) => {
            alert(err);
        });
    }
```

system ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v9.2.0
    npm               : 6.1.0 
    OS                : Linux 4.15

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/anandhsp21/Android/Sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is solved by updating the dependencies in package.json file

> My older package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --port 8100"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/linkedin": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/twitter-connect": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@ionic2-extra/calendar": "^0.1.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "branch-cordova-sdk": "^2.6.24",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.10.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "~2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.0.4",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.1.0",
    "datepicker-ionic2": "^2.3.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "multiple-date-picker": "^2.1.6",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "twitter-connect-plugin": "git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "postcss": "6.0.14",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "ionic3Sample: An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
      "cordova-custom-config": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      },
      "twitter-connect-plugin": {
        "TWITTER_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "TWITTER_SECRET": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "FABRIC_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-appavailability": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "APP_NAME": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "branch-cordova-sdk": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Then I removed current node modules in my project.

```
rm -r node_modules
```

Then I manually updated these dependencies in package.json file

> My current updated package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --port 8100"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/linkedin": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/twitter-connect": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ionic2-extra/calendar": "^0.1.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "branch-cordova-sdk": "^2.6.24",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.10.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "~2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.0.4",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.1.0",
    "datepicker-ionic2": "^2.3.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "multiple-date-picker": "^2.1.6",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "twitter-connect-plugin": "git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "postcss": "6.0.14",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "ionic3Sample: An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
      "cordova-custom-config": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      },
      "twitter-connect-plugin": {
         "TWITTER_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "TWITTER_SECRET": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "FABRIC_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-appavailability": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "APP_NAME": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "branch-cordova-sdk": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And also I faced some plugin conflict issues between facebook plugin with barcode scanner plugin.

The above issue is solved by updating values in project.properties file

Path

```
/Your-project/platforms/android/project.properties


# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/mobile-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/mobile-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
cordova.gradle.include.3=twitter-connect-plugin/mobile-twitter.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:27.+
```

Then I did the following commands to work properly

```
npm install

ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova build android

ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Hope it some one helps.